# Causative classes in Cantonese

Tags: classifiers, causative, cantonese

Recently me and WavesWashSands had a conversation about Cantonese and it's causatives. *zing2, gaau2, tam3, gik1, haak3* etc. A lot of these look like they are just based on classes of moods.

But are there more of these? Do other languages have *causative classes* ?